# jQuery validate stepwise validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Does jquery validate support stepwise validation, i.e. I have implemented a questionnaire with 20 questions in a single form showing and hiding each question stepwise (go on with a button). When pressing the button, the next question is shown.

I guess I would have to trigger the validation on the clicked-event and switching the validation for the current question on.

Comment: It's possible to do with `valid()` but you have to attach your current code if you expect to receive full answer.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4x4wknku/1/) code.

Html:

```
<div class="Steps Step_1">
    <h1>Step 01</h1>
    <input id="txtStep_1" type="text" value="" />
    <button id="btnNext" data-next="Step_2">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="Steps Step_2" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Step 02</h1>
    <input id="txtStep_2" type="text" value="" />
    <button id="btnNext" data-next="Step_3">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="Steps Step_3" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Step 03</h1>
    <input id="txtStep_3" type="text" value="" />
    <button id="btnNext">Next</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var current = 1;
$('button').on('click', function() {
    if (!window["ValidateStep_" + current]())
        alert('fill form..');

    current++;
    $('.Steps').hide();
    $('.Step_' + current).show();
})

window.ValidateStep_1 = function() {
    return true;
}

window.ValidateStep_2 = function() {
    return true;
}

window.ValidateStep_3 = function() {
    return false;
}
```